# Why does Pylons use StackedObjectProxies instead of threading.local?

Tags: python, pylons

It seems like threading.local is more straightforward and more robust.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

StackedObjectProxy uses a threading.local underneath it. Pylons doesn't use plain threading.locals for 2 reasons:

1) it'd be a more intrusive API than a proxy. E.g. request().POST.get('file') vs request.POST.get('file')

2) StackedObjectProxys are not only thread safe, but also "request safe" -- meaning it's safe for a Pylons application to be embedded in another and reference the same proxy objects. The need for this kind of safety is rare, but is certainly a possibility with how easy it is for WSGI apps to call other WSGI apps + the use of global objects

See the [paste.registry docs](http://pythonpaste.org/modules/registry.html#module-paste.registry) for more information

Answer (score 1):

Because `threading.local` is *new in Python 2.4*. The `StackedObjectProxy` uses threading.local if it can.

Comment: Python 2.4 came out in 2004 so I'm not sure "new" is the right word.

Comment: I'm just kind of quoting http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.local ;-)